# How can I store multiple values in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polymer

pretty simple question.

I am trying to learn polymer and have made a survey.
For one of the questions I would like to assign multiple values as the answer but for some reason I can only get it working with one value.

```
"survey": [

        {
            "type": "picker",
            "question": "Please rate out of 5",
            "min": 1,
            "max": 5,
            "answer": 5
        },
```

This returns a positive result when the user selects 5 but when the user selects 1-4 it is incorrect.

What I would like to do is store multiple values in the 'answer' field so that if the user selects 1-5 they all register as correct.

How can I do this? I have tried

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

and it still doesn't work.

EDIT:

Here is the value html added in for polymer to create the slider.

```
 <paper-slider id="slider" min="{{quiz.min}}" max="{{quiz.max}}" step="{{quiz.step || 1}}" immediateValue="{{value}}"></paper-slider>
```

Comment: Did you try  `"answer": [1,2,3,4,5]` ?

Comment: Yes lol I listed that in my description, thanks though.

Comment: How are you comparing answer?

Comment: Hey, please see my edited update. I've shown the polymer html I am using to refer to the slider values. The values are set in the .json file. 
I am just trying to select more than one value for an answer but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `'answer'` as an array in the json like

```
     var survey = {
            "type": "picker",
            "question": "Please rate out of 5",
            "min": 1,
            "max": 5,
            "answer": [1,2,3]
        }
```

And whenever the user inputs something you just have to push the value like this

```
console.log(survey); // Array has just 3 elements.
survey['answer'].push(4);
console.log(survey); // The value 4 would have been inserted.
```

How you are pushing the values?

Look at the 
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/fknm7ayj/1/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. 
Unfortunately neither of the options work :/ 
When I try either of them all of the values inputted by the user still return negative. 

When I put in just a single value ie. 5 
It works fine

Comment: Check out my edt. How are you pushing the elements if the user selects more than one option?

Comment: Hi Again! The user is actually selecting it on a slider that slides left to right from 1 - 5. So the user is only able to select one option/value at a time. 
I have tried your code again, but it is still not returning any of the values correct. When I enter in just 5, or 4, or any single value, it brings back answer as correct. When I enter in multiple values like you have shown in an array, all of them are incorrect. :(

Comment: It would be helpful if you could just post the code on what you are doing when the user selects the option from the slides

Comment: Check the edited version in my original post. 
Is that enough?
I am working off of the topeka source files https://github.com/polymer/topeka

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it might work using children elements.

```
"survey": [
    {
       "type": "picker",
       "question": "please rate out of 5",
       "answer": [
            {
                value: "1",
                value: "2",
                value: "3",
                value: "4",
                value: "5",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Reference: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html

Comment: I have tried this answer but it seems like I am getting some sort of syntax error. 
Here is a screenshot of the code. http://imgur.com/EWdBIeW